# Access Denied reading list with RunWithElevatedPrivileges

Tags: runwithelevatedprivileges, ssom

I am trying to read a list with a user without read permissions.
I am using runWithElevatedPriviliges and I get this error:

> Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or
>   access this resource.

I have made sure that the user becomes SHAREPOINT\SYSTEM after

> RunWithElevatedPrivileges

To add, SHAREPOINT\SYSTEM has full control on the list.

```
   Guid siteId = SPContext.Current.Site.ID;
            Guid webId = SPContext.Current.Web.ID;

            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteId))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(webId))
                    {

                        SPUser spuser = web.CurrentUser;
                        tb1.Text = "user:" + spuser.LoginName;
                        this.Controls.Add(tb1);

                        splist = web.Lists["List1"];


                        lvwp = new ListViewWebPart();
                        lvwp.ListName = splist.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();
                        lvwp.ViewGuid = splist.DefaultView.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();
                        lvwp.ChromeType = System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PartChromeType.None;


                        this.Controls.Add(lvwp);


                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Any Idea, what's wrong?

**Edit:**
I see that I can even read and print on the screen the list items. Even so, the ListViewPart is not added and the Access Denied message shows up

**Edit2:**
the error shows up at this point:

```
 this.Controls.Add(lvwp);
```

I've even tried moving this line out of the RunWithElevatedPrivileges but with no luck

Comment: Elevated code will not run as SharePoint\System but as the application pool accound of the current web application

Comment: Thanks  Robert Lindgren but the application pool account has full control on the list and on the site collection.

Comment: I do not think you can use the ListViewWebPart, it would not surprise me if it uses SPContext internally. You would need to do your own display in an SPGridView or something similar